# Extend variable-name class

Tags: php, php-7

```
class A {}
$nameA = 'A';
$objA = new $nameA();
```

This works. But

```
$objB = new class extends $nameA { ... };
```

this doesn't work (`PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING or T_NAMESPACE or T_NS_SEPARATOR on line 1`).

Is there any method to extend a variable-name class?
(One obvious method is `eval`)

Comment: How do you know exactly what to _extend_, i.e. from where do you get the previous method signature(s)? Or do you plan to only add new, _unrelated_ functionality?

Comment: Parent class is given dynamically through dependency injection, and here we just can assert that its signatures are known. Indeed this use case might sound strange.

Comment: Could you place the use-case somewhere on a map that has [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), [aspect oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), something-else as its corners?

Comment: Basically what I'm trying is to modify the behavior of a class used inside a framework. As defined and used in the framework, I can't change the interface. It has hundreds of methods, which would change in the future, so defining "relay" methods that call original method internally is not an option too.

Comment: This is not supported and will not be supported. Just like `class A extends $var {}` is not allowed -- anonymous classes change nothing about that.

Comment: "It has hundreds of methods," - really? Well, _there_'s your problem ;-) But if you let a tool/script generate the code not even that is insurmountable. You can either let it create one class that delegates all those calls or let it scan for all existing classes you're interested in and generate derived classes that override the specific methods you need or some combination of that. A tiny bit like eval() but pre-execution.

Comment: @ NikiC  "and will not be supported" like never? Wait a second, let me write an rfc for that (after joining the dev team that is....). I'll call it ...something with "prototype" in the title. Basically joining the methods' and other properties' lookup table, some obscure php/javascript mishmash :-D  just kidding.